# 18.04 and 19.10 Server randomly freeze

Tags: server, freeze, crash, 19.10

I'm new to linux and I hope you can help me. 
I got the issue that my Ubuntu server 18.04 and new installation 19.10 on the same machine is freezing randomly. I can only recover my system by pressing the reset button.

I installed on this server only Samba and Plex since with the current stability it's not usefull to spend the time with installing more. So the installation is pretty lean.

My question would be where to find a useful log file and getting some ideas what could be the possible reason. Because I got he hardware cheap and don't want to by something new. The Hardware ran previously on Windows with out any issues.

Thank you in advance for your help.

System:

- AMD Ryzen 1400
- Gigabyte GA-AX370-Gaming K3 Mainboard (https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-K3-rev-10#kf)
- 8 GB RAM
- 1 SSD
- 7 HDDs
- 350 W BeQuiet Powersupply
- Gigabit Ethernet network card PCIe
- Ubunut 19.10 installed on an SSD

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,8Gi       957Mi       5,6Gi       5,0Mi       1,2Gi       6,6Gi
Swap:         4,0Gi          0B       4,0Gi
```

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
F42e
```

One newer Bios version Available F50

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`, and use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your BIOS version. Then we can go to the Gigabyte site and check what the most current version is. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your answer. I added the values to my question. Sorry for the late response my kids haven't gave me the time to answer.

Comment: Please change kernel and desktop manager(if you have). And use it for a while.

Comment: Yes, there's one newer BIOS for your machine, version F50a. https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-K3-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios Also, please show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @manowar_manowar how can I cange the used kernel? I currently got neither a display nor a graficscard in my server. Since it is a server version of ubuntu I haven't installed any desktop so there should be no desktop manager installed.

Comment: @heynnema when entering `vm.swappiness = 60`

Comment: Did you do the BIOS update yet? Also, some early Ryzen processors have a problem running under Linux, and AMD was replacing those processors. Google that.